# Calculate time consumption of query

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have  a select query, i would like to run it 50 times in parallel(to load test) ie. 50 independent times(a separate process).

if i run like this

```
for (int i=0;i<=49;i++)
{
 //record start time before the query
 //Code that runs the select query...
 //record end time after the query
}
```

I need to test the select query for 50 times, do I need to use 50 different threads or running that query in for loop 50 times, which is the correct approach?

Is there better way to check the consumption time of the query for say 50 times ? Do i need to use threads? I am not sure how to use Threads, don't have much idea of threaded programming, any sample will help.

Comment: Are you looking at this from the code (C#) perspective or database (SQL) perspective?

Comment: Test SQL query in C# code.

Comment: StopWatch class may be helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: Thanks, my question was if I need to test the select query for 50 times, do I need to use 50 different threads or running that query in for loop 50 times?

Comment: @Sharpeye500 - well I would say you should test it the same way your application will use it, will the application make parallel queries or not? There is your answer.

Comment: So you want to run it 50 times in parallel and you are asking if simple loop will do that.  Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you doing this? Is this for performance evaluation purposes, as a fun hobby project, or part of production code?

Since it is a Select query, you shouldn't run into the same kinds of locking/transaction-breaking problems you would get trying to implement async Insert/Update/Delete queries. One thing to know is, don't run them in a loop, since that's synchronous. You can set up the queries in a loop if you need to, but you'll need to use a Service Broker to run them. Take a look at [this excellent article](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/) to get started. For the C# side, take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh873191.aspx) if you're running 2012.

Comment: This is for load testing of the query from UI, so that, when 50 different users hit the same query, at the same time, I would like to record the consumption time of each user(s).